# Is there a design pattern for separating data into spaces?

Tags: database, permissions

I'm working on a problem where application data needs to be separated into spaces;

- a production space
- a demo space
- a test space
- a training space
- ...

Some product data is shared across spaces, but almost all user data should be read/write per space controlled by a permission system.

Is there a common design pattern for this? I'm concerned about the risk of accidentally mixing data between spaces, i.e. test space data ending up in the production space.

Thanks!